# Counting leading spaces in Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, spaces

I guess the title is quite clear. I tried the below solutions, without success.
My function works great with `Strings`, but not with `cells`.
Any clue very welcome.

```
Function nbLeadingSpaces(str As Variant) As Integer
    Dim trimmed As String
    trimmed = LTrim(str)
    'works with strings, not with cells
    nbLeadingSpaces = InStr(1, str, Left(trimmed, 1), vbTextCompare) - 1
    'same issue
    'nbLeadingSpaces = Len(str) - Len(LTrim(str))
End Function
```

I need this in order to do stuff based on a kind of *text outline* where the number of leading spaces will show if a row is a *main row* or *sub row* (several levels). VBA seems to automatically TRIM the cell contents 8-/

---

### Edit

Sorry to all, I am stupid (at least sometimes). There WERE no **spaces** in front of those cells, but an **indent** :-)
Problem solved then, I can just get the `rng.IndentLevel` and that's it.
Anyway all your remarks help me reanalyze the issue, and I will leave this question, which might help another lost mind one day :-)

Comment: try with `trimmed = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(str)`

Comment: @ScottCraner how could that help when VBA ignores the leading spaces (when they come from a cell) anyway ? Did you try this recommendation ?

Comment: `nbLeadingSpaces = Len(str) - Len(LTrim(str))` works for me as expected when I use it as a UDF. How are you trying to use your function?

Comment: @JohnColeman dealing with strings or **cells**? That is the question

Comment: When you say 'text outline', do you mean the space are added to the value of the cell per conditional formatting?

Comment: I put `"    abc"` in cell A1 (with 4 spaces before a) and then in A2 I put `=nbLeadingSpaces(A1)` and the expected 4 pops up.

Comment: Same as @JohnColeman, works fine with cells, as long as the value of the cell contains the spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to all, I am stupid (at least sometimes). There WERE no **spaces** in front of those cells, but an **indent** :-)
Problem solved then, I can just get the `rng.IndentLevel` and that's it.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about that property so I probably would have made the same mistake.